# Can a mod please update the [faq] tag wiki?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta-faq, tag-wiki-excerpt

Can a mod please update the summary box and "about" section of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag wiki? The current text, which is copied below, is pretty useless.

> Lying prone, drooling and gibbering in the gultch [sic], these posts are your quick guide in what, how and where of the sites [sic]. Naturally, no one reads any of it.

It'll have to be a mod because all FAQ entries are CW, which means nobody will ever get edit rights the normal way. (The bronze badge for a given tag is the prerequisite for editing that tag's wiki, but CW answers don't count towards the badge.) Yes, there are a few people with ancient non-CW FAQ answers, but relying on them isn't the answer.

At a minimum, it'd be nice to see a link to the [main FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) there, along with an indication that [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions comprise **the** quasi-official Stack Exchange FAQ. Based on the sort of activity that's commonly seen here, the FAQ is one of the main reasons people ever visit MSO. Or, at least, would be, if they knew their questions had already been addressed. But that's getting into a separate issue.

Comment: How did it end up this way? A rogue mod abusing their powers?

Comment: @Al Looks like [random](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) went [a bit crazy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63271/revisions). Which isn't exactly out of character for him

Comment: @Al It's not so much rogue abuse as it is simply [par for the course](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314?tab=activity "Check out the revision summaries").

Comment: @Grace note - I find the [revisions tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions) far more interesting.  Where does he come up with this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed by a moderator of the [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63271/revisions) kind to the following:

> These posts are your quick guide to the what, how and where of the StackExchange network